# Count new users and users who came back

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

[image: screenshot of my table]

I want to find count of new customers (cust_id) (like first found record) per month and count of customers who came back in the next month (for example, first record in March, 2016, and this cust_id have a record in April, 2016). The third column I want to calculate the percentage of users who came back.

Example:

```
+--------------------+-----------+----------------+------------+
| month_registration | new_users | returned_users | percentage |
+--------------------+-----------+----------------+------------+
| March, 2016        |        36 |             12 |       0.33 |
| April, 2016        |        44 |             11 |       0.25 |
| May, 2016          |        50 |              5 |        0.1 |
+--------------------+-----------+----------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select date_trunc('month', ship_date),
       count(distinct custid) filter (where date_trunc('month', first_ship_date) = date_trunc('month', ship_date)) as new_customers,
       count(distinct custid) filter (where date_trunc('month', first_ship_date) < date_trunc('month', ship_date)) as returning_customers,
       ( count(distinct custid) filter (where date_trunc('month', first_ship_date) < date_trunc('month', ship_date)) * 1.0 /
         count(distinct custid) filter (where date_trunc('month', first_ship_date) = date_trunc('month', ship_date))
       ) as ratio    
from (select t.*, min(ship_date) over (partition by custid) as first_ship_date
      from t
     ) t
group by date_trunc('month', ship_date)
```

Comment: metabase says there is a syntax error in the second line, but i can't find it. :c can you help me, please?

Comment: @andyxchapman . . . That `where` should have been (and now is `filter where`.  If you have an old version of Postgres, you might need to use a `case` expression.

Comment: thank you! i tried to modify you query so i can find customers who returned on the second month after the first appearance, but it looks weird (here is my screenshot from metabase: https://imgur.com/a/CqChKVm). as you see, there is 4 new customers in July, but there is 5 of them who came back in the second month. where am I wrong? :c